# Как создать ползунок внутри игрового процесса на юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно создать ползунок внутри игры, который будет отвечать за течение времени. То есть, если пользователь продвигает его вправо, то время ускоряется, влево - наоборот замедляется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать. Находил информацию только с работой в меню, но не в самом игровом процессе.

Comment: Так в Unity в UI есть уже готовый ползунок и событие на нем OnValueChanged(или что-то такое). Устанавливает значения min/max для этого ползунка, ставишь галочку числа с плавающей точкой, даёшь событию метод, который будет менять Time.timeScale = polzunok.Value

Comment: Вам помогло мое решение?

Comment: @Methorn
Да, спасибо)